# Vertical viewport was given unbounded width

Tags: listview, flutter

I am new to Flutter and got stuck with apparently something trivial which I can't figure out.

Here is a stateful class:

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  Menu({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  MenuState createState() => MenuState();
}

class MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Container(
      child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
          new FetchSummary(context: context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From this class I am calling FetchSummary. The idea is to fetch data from a JSON file which will dynamically change later.

```
class FetchSummary extends StatefulWidget {
  FetchSummary({Key key, this.context}) : super(key: key);
  final BuildContext context;

  @override
  FetchSummaryState createState() => FetchSummaryState();
}

class FetchSummaryState extends State<FetchSummary> {
  var _jsonFile = "assets/db-summaryData.json";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
        future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(_jsonFile),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          var myData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
          } else {
            //List<Post> yourPosts = snapshot.data.posts;
            return Column(children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      //shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: myData.length,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                            //margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1),
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 164, 147, 0.5),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: new Text(
                                "Dummy Text",
                              ),
                            ));
                      }))
            ]);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

In this Widget, at the moment, I am just trying to send back some text before fetching anything from myData JSON object. However when I try to run it starts complaining as below:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
**Vertical viewport was given unbounded width.**

Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView file:///D:/FlutterDev/Dashboard/dashboard/lib/main.dart:149:35
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderViewport.performResize.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1191:15)
```

### Updated

If I move/copy the FutureBuilder to the calling function instead of calling that as a class it works fine.**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
        future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(_jsonFile),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          var myData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
..............
```

### Final update

I replaced the calling code from this:

```
return new Container(
  child: new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
      new FetchSummary(context: context),
    ],
  ),
);
```

to this:

```
return new Container(
  child:
      new FetchSummary(context: context),
  );
```

And it worked. I think it didn't like the Row widget.

Comment: try removing flexible and column both

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return  ListView.builder(
                      //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      //shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: myData.length,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                            //margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1),
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 164, 147, 0.5),
                            child: ListTile(
                              title: new Text(
                                "Dummy Text",
                              ),
                            ));
                      });
```

Comment: enable `shrinkWrap: true,`

Comment: Didn't work. I left it in the post just to give an idea that I have tried these things

Answer (score 0):

To run it in the Row widget you may have to give the container certain width to fit in

Like this :

```
return new Container(
 width: 50,
 child: new Row(
   children: <Widget>[
     new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
     new FetchSummary(context: context),
   ],
 ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I can live with out Row. If needed I will test that out.